# Output Style Float working oddly with webkit engine

Tags: singularitygs

I'm working on a grid where I'm using output_style = false for elements containing content. Those elements are made into squares using a simple javascript function. While the grid works as intended, I find that in Safari and Chrome, the width of some of the elements is off by a pixel until I resize the browser. If I resize back to the original size, it still works. This is not the case in Firefox, where it works perfectly when the page is loaded. Is this a known bug, and is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using $(window).resize(), which is called 1 second after the page has completed loading. Does the trick.